# Reading from fifo with blocking

Tags: c, named-pipes

I have a fifo (named pipe) in /tmp/foo.
I want to read from the fifo, if the fifo is empty the programm ought to sleep.
At the moment this is my solution:

```
char buf [7];
FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/foo", "r");
while(!fgets(buf, 7, f)){
    sleep(1);
}
```

The fgets only blocks until some data is written to the fifo. But if the fifo is empty fgets doesn't block.
Is there an elegant solution to read only if data is available and block if not?
I'm working on Unix (Raspian)

===Solution===

I solved it in Python.
@Jonathan Leffler it is right that fopen blocks until an other process open the pipe.

The solution of the issue is to close the file after reading and reopen it.
To prevent the second process (eg cat) to keep it open, it is enough to close the file and wait a short time.
This can look like this:

```
while True:
    f = open('/tmp/HA/temp', 'w') #blocks until pipe is opend somewhere else
    f.write("foo") #access file
    f.close() #close it
    time.sleep(0.1) #second programm might end file access
```

Comment: Normally, the `fopen()` will block until there is a process (usually another process) that has the FIFO open for writing — and a process opening a FIFO for writing will be blocked in the open until there is a process (usually another process) that has the FIFO open for reading.  Once the processes get past the open, the reader block until either there is data to read or all the writers have closed the FIFO.  The writers can write until the FIFO reaches its limit (usually 4-64 KiB — it depends on the system), or until there is no reader with the FIFO open. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The behaviour you describe is not the default behaviour.  There are ways to get the behaviour you describe, but they involve tinkering with settings on the file descriptor that belongs to the file stream.  To convince me that you've got a real problem, you'd have to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).  That'd be at least a complete reader program, an indication of how you're running the writer.  The reader should be error checking the `fopen()` call; it should be printing the data it reads; and we should see what you're providing as input and what you get as output vs what you expect.

Comment: You should also identify the platform you're running on.  I'm 100% confident of my answer for Unix-based systems.  I'm 98% confident for Windows-based systems.  Otherwise, I'm not sure.  The compiler and library versions might be relevant, but probably not.  It depends on you having an MCVE that reproduces the problem reliably on your system and doesn't reproduce it on mine (which would be macOS Sierra 10.12.3).  I don't think we'll need to get that involved, though.